# Nodemailer contact form not working from phone

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, nodemailer

I've made a contact form using React, and for the backend I'm using CORS, Express, and Nodemailer. I've deployed the application on Netlify, and I'm encountering an issue when attempting to send test emails from my mobile phone. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Error submitting form: TypeError {  }
r@webkit-masked-url://hidden/:27:166011
value@webkit-masked-url://hidden/:27:182883
@webkit-masked-url://hidden/:27:184904
Load failed
```

However I can successfully send emails from my computer.

I have a `server.cjs` with this config:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));
console.log(process.env.EMAIL_USER);
console.log(process.env.EMAIL_PASS);

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS,
  },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Received a contact request");
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const message = req.body.message;
  const mail = {
    from: name,
    to: "blabla@gmail.com",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json(error);
    } else {
      res.json({ code: 200, status: "Message Sent" });
    }
  });
});
```

and for the frontend part:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setButtonText(text[isSpanish ? "spanish" : "english"].sending);
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/contact";
  try {
      let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formDetails),
      });

      setButtonText(text[isSpanish ? "spanish" : "english"].send);
      let result = await response.json();
      setFormDetails(formInitialDetails);
      if (result.code === 200) {
        setStatus({ success: true, message: text[isSpanish ? "spanish" : "english"].successMessage });
      } else {
        setStatus({ success: false, message: text[isSpanish ? "spanish" : "english"].errorMessage });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting form:", error);
      setStatus({ success: false, message: text[isSpanish ? "spanish" : "english"].errorMessage });
    }
  };
```

I've tried installing PM2 globally to ensure that Node is always running. I've tried both with iPhone and Android